# How to redirect https request to www as default in ASP.NET MVC hosted on Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl

I am very new to asp.net mvc. I recently created a website and hosted on Azure. I recently turned OFF the SSL on my cloudflare acoount. I will not use it further.

Currently, the site is working fine if I type www.domain.com. But if I type https://domain.com AND domain.com directly in the address bar is not working. It is showing some message like this [See the attachment]

How can I fix this issue, to redirect all requests coming to my website either https://domain.com, www.domain.com, domain.com to redirected only to www.domain.com

[image]

My web.config file code[which is not working]

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www"  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />

                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

**EDIT:** As I said before, I turned OFF the SSL on cloudflare. When I turn it on it is correctly redirecting with the above code. But when I turn it off it is not redirecting. I want to turn off SSL completely and redirect to www for all requests.